# Issue with data type conversion in pyspark notebook in azure synapse analytics

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I am getting the following error while saving the file to ADLS Gen2. I am trying to merge all files in a location. There is a particular column in all the file which has different data type, hence setting up the schema to have column 'value' to string and then merge.

I tried explicitly converting the column to string as well, still its not working.

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:com.microsoft.spark.notebook.visualization.display.getDisplayResultForIPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 34 in stage 9.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 34.3 in stage 9.0 (TID 463) (vm-d2249026 executor 5): org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: Parquet column cannot be converted in file abfss://container@dsprdsa.dfs.core.windows.net/20230626T211927.parquet. Column: [value], Expected: string, Found: DOUBLE

```
import json
schema_json ='{"fields": [{"name": "column","nullable": true,"type": "string","metadata":{}},{"name": "value","nullable": true,"type": "string","metadata":{}},{"name": "quality","nullable": true,"type": "string","metadata":{}},{"name": "timestamp","nullable": true,"type":"timestamp","metadata":{}}]}'
schema = StructType.fromJson(json.loads(schema_json))

df = spark.read.schema(schema).option('mergeSchema',"True").parquet(path)

from pyspark.sql.types import *
df = df.withColumn("value",col("value").cast(StringType()))

df.printSchema()


root
 |-- column: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- quality: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)



df.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").option("header","true").save(lc_dest)
```